# How to see before / after video side by side in Premiere Pro?

Tags: adobe-premiere

I'm new to Premiere Pro. Can't figure out how to do this. Let's say I want to apply stabiliser and compare it against my original video. I want to have them playing in Premiere Pro side by side (original and one with all effects applied), but I can't figure out how to set it up.